# Read different nfc tags from different activities

Tags: android, nfc

at the moment i've an activity A that succesfully read the content of a tag, but now I should be able to read another TAG from Activity B, both tags are plainText but Activity A emulates the reading of a tag about an opera while Activity B must emulate a payment so the user should be already on those activity when he reads the tag.

I've surfed the web about this, but didn't find nothing, and i'm not enough skilled with nfc to go over that alone.

Thanks in advance for your help, I dont think code is needed as it's more a theorical question, but I can provide it.

Just to be more specifici, I'm using Mifare Ultralight as tag.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I found a method to manage rad tags on different activities.

Basically I had to implement a Foreground Dispatcher in an Activity and then extends that Activity from Activity A and Activity B, so each one read a tag only if already on foregorund and won't be seen by the system picker.

Comment: Why don't you just have two seperate foreground dispatches in both Activities? You can disable the foreground dispatch in the onDestroy method

Answer (score 0):

I done something similar yet. There was three types of NFC tags, and I had to launch different activities of my app, if the user scan different NFC tags. I played around a while, but I figured out the solution:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.ProductInfo"
        android:label="Product Info:"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>

            <data android:mimeType="text/sbapp/info" />
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name=".ui.ShoppingList"
        android:label="Shopping List:"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        <intent-filter>
            <data android:mimeType="text/sbapp/buy" />
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

The NFC tags contained the following:
content type:
text /   sbapp/buy   (instead of text/plain)
data: 34345 (productID)
```

Yes, I created a custom NFC tag, where I replaced the plain with my custom thing.

```
content type:
text /   sbapp/info   (instead of text/plain)
data: 34345 (productID)
```